# Iteration loop to import text files in R

Tags: r, matrix, read.table

I am new to programming/coding and I have been asked to:

1. Load 15 text files (each text file contains 2 columns) as my data set as a list and save the list as a variable.
2. Use a `for` loop to import data from within the text files into a temporary matrix N using `read.table` function, number of iterations = length of list = 15. The `for` loop will eventually save data in permanent matrix X.
3. Append the second column of N to last row of X.
4. Extract filenames of each text file and save them in a character vector called *sam*.
5. After the loop, create a new row vector containing the first column of N.

Can you please have a look at my code and see where I am going wrong? Many thanks.

**Importing 15 files into a matrix (X)**

```
filelist = dir(path="Z:/Assignment R/IR", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
           full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
           ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE)
```

**Confirming length of list**

```
length(filelist)
```

**Defining X matrix as empty to begin with**

```
X = 0

for (i in filelist) {

  N = as.matrix(read.table(filelist), header = FALSE, sep = "\t"))
```

**Appending the second column of N to last row of X**

```
  X = rbind(X,(t(N[,2]))
```

**Extracting filenames of each text file and save them in a character vector called sam**

```
  sam = c(i)
}
```

**Creating a new row vector containing the first column of N.**

```
Wavenumbers = t(N[,1])
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what's going wrong here, could you add more details to your question?

Comment: This site works best when you have one specific question. Asking to review your assignment is a little out of scope here.

Comment: My assignment comprises of 500+ lines - I'm stuck at this little bit. I wouldn't ask if I wasn't - if you don't want to help that's fine :)